# Is spring session and cookies still relevant since there is spring security and JWT

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

I started a spring boot project some months ago and used Spring JDBC session with cookies. the application has to do with payment.In order to get the user in session i got the cookie from the HTTPRequestservelet and passed the ID in it to the JDBC session to get the user in session. Now i have read about spring security and JWT and it seems like it does the same thing but in a more secured, standardized way, plus spring security comes with Bcrypt, so my question now is since I am planning to change the JWT and spring security, is my JDBC session and cookie still relevant ?.

Answer (score 2):

A cookie is just a small piece of information that is sent from and to the server in request and response to maintain session related information. You can always ignore cookies (not just while using JWTs) as long as you can establish a mechanism by which you can store and retrieve session related information.

JWTs are used to send and receive authentication & authorization information and **NOT** session related information, i.e you can not change a JWT when, say, a user adds an item to their cart.

So, you may want to use cookies (or any other mechanism) in addition to JWTs for tracking session information.

Edit : I recently discovered, sending JWT in a cookie is one of the known best practices. So now, you have best of both the worlds.

Comment: So how is it possible to use sessions with spring security, will the authentication happen before the sessioning or vice versa ?

Comment: At what point in time do you start the session totally depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you decide to go ahead with cookies you can just use `response.addCookie(new Cookie("key", value))`
Just because you are using Spring Security and JWT, does not mean you have to change how you used to handle cookies earlier. It can still remain the same.

Comment: this is how i get my cookies from the request request.getCookies(), so is it possible to use this cookie and get the user which i can then  be used in my customs spring security class overridden  configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder)  method.

Comment: As I understand, you want to get user information (username/password) from cookies and verify it.
In which case, you need to provide your custom implementation of `UserDetailsService` where in you create a `User` object and pass it to Spring Security. And in your `configure` method, ask `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` to use your custom implementation of `UserDetailsService`.
_Hope this answers your query._

Comment: okay, so another question i have is, The authentication Builder cross references the username and Bcrytpassword on every Url that is secured, this could be a problem a because if the user enters a url that has been secured by spring security, he has to be redirected to the loginForm page every time, how can this issue be resolved, so that the user only gets authenticated with his username and password once and spring security uses that details throughout the apps life cycle without him being always redirected to the Loginform ?

Comment: I assume you are usimg JWTs here. So everytime you make a request to a secure url, you need to pass the JWT in `Authorization` header and `Bearer` schema. This way, sprig security knows that the user has been authenticated previously.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170280/discussion-between-appzone-oto-and-pranjal-gore).